# Remove extra characters from URL after Disqus is installed

Tags: disqus

After installing Disqus, some URLs are being modified to include extra characters with #

Example: /#.URsPE-hf3PX

How can I disable that?

Comment: Disqus doesn't modify/add to any URLs, it must be another source. Where do you see this, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This was a documented issue with AddThis. This question is closed.